# Grails email and url validator for UTF8 values

Tags: validation, grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-validation

I ave some Grails app where I am using validation in domain. I have something like this:

```
  website nullable: true, url: true
  emailAddress nullable: true, email: true
```

My problem is that those validations are failing for valid entries:

```
postk.gs-überlingen@yahoo.com - valid email -> default email validation fails
überlingen@yahoo.com - same

http://www.moselstübchen.de/ - valid website url -> Grails url validator fails
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You can add matches http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/matches.html. you only need valid regexp for german

Comment: @baxxabit why only for german? I think that for all languages except english.

Comment: I mean that gs-überlingen isn't english.

Comment: still, is a valid email address and the email validator from Grails says that isn't. And there is nowhere in docs saying that is email validator for english email addresses, it says that is email validator. It should validate all valid email addresses as valid. I think this is a bug.

Comment: Accordingly with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Ongoing internationalization efforts are underway to allow non-ASCII characters to be used in both the local and domain parts of an email address, allowing addresses such as: Pelé@example.com and 甲斐@黒川.日本 but these are still constrained by the current generation of email servers and clients.

My native language is russian, but I don't use email witn non-ansii symbols.

Comment: I think, it is not a bug, supported languages currently: 

Latin Alphabet (with diacritics): Pelé@example.com
Greek Alphabet: δοκιμή@παράδειγμα.δοκιμή
Japanese Characters: 甲斐@黒川.日本
Cyrillic Characters: чебурашка@ящик-с-апельсинами.рф, but not german

Comment: Also try to check your email: http://verify-email.org/

Comment: According to this: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6531#page-5, that is a valid email address. Also the website that is failing validation i grails is a valid website, can be accessed from any browser